# How to disable previous input field on dynamically adding new input field in form in angular?

Tags: angularjs

In my form I am adding new input field dynamically on click of add icon.
How will I make the previous input field read only, when I click on add icon so that only current field value can be changed.

Comment: Hi, please provide your code, otherwise it's difficult to help you out! :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.